# How can i succeed this complex CakePHP multimodel SQL request?

Tags: sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I need help to make a SQL request using CakePHP.

So I have a table publications:

```
Id

Network_id

User_id

Content
```

And I have 3 table linking:

```
Publication to users: publications_users

Publication to clans: publications_clans

Publication to alliances: publications_alliances
```

In input of this request I provide an array containing ID of `clans`, another containing ID of `alliance`, a `User_id` and a `Network_id`.

I need to make a CakePHP request that will give me all publications who belong to my array of `clans` && my array of `alliances` && my `User_id` && my `Network_id`.

The problem is that I don’t know how to create such a complex using CakePHP $this->Publication->find(« all »,array()) syntax.

Is it at least possible to do that this way? 
Does anybody can help me succeed to do that please because I’m going to need to create a lot of such a complex request and I have no idea of how to do.

Thank you a lot in advance for your precious help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use Containable behavior, read this http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use proper Join Query and then parse using CakePHP function instead of using 2 or 3 different queries and then storing it in arrays.